# Multiple Jira instances on a single Tomcat 6 server?

Tags: tomcat6, jira, webcontext

I have a feeling this is a stupid question but I can't find the answer anywhere...

I need to deploy 2 Jira instances on asingle Tomcat server, I can't figure out how to pass in the jira.home property
The [documentation](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Setting+your+JIRA+Home+Directory?clicked=jirahelp) says I need to:-

> Add a web context property called 'jira.home' — this property is set in different files depending on your application server. For example, for Tomcat (and therefore for JIRA Standalone), you will need to configure the server.xml file. For other application servers you may need to configure the web.xml file, or set 'Context parameter' options on the deployment UI of the application server, etc. Note that If you have specified a JIRA home in jira-application.properties (ie. the recommended method), it will override your web context property.

I was hoping something like this would work.

```
<Context jira.home="d:/jira/data" path="" docBase="D:\Jira\atlassian-jira-enterprise-4.1\dist-tomcat\tomcat-6\atlassian-jira-4.1.war" debug="0">
    <Resource name="jdbc/JiraDS" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            username="sa"
            password="*****"
            driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://*****:1433/jira41_519;user=****;password=****"
        />

    <Resource name="UserTransaction" auth="Container" type="javax.transaction.UserTransaction"
    factory="org.objectweb.jotm.UserTransactionFactory" jotm.timeout="60"/>
    <Manager pathname=""/>

</Context>
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ah ha! 
This is what I was looking for!

```
<Parameter name="jira.home" value="d:/jira/dataResearch" override="false"/>
```

Comment: It turns out thouuhg that you can't run two Jira instances on a single Tomcat instance. I ended up installing Tomcat twice and deploying jira to each :(